# Doctrine inconsistently and silently fails to load model

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

Ok, I'm using Doctrine2 in Codeigniter along the lines of [Joel Verhagen](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/) and things have been working fine, but now I have a mysterious issue.

When destroying an item things work fine:

```
$delete = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Item')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $item));
$this->doctrine->em->remove($delete);
$this->doctrine->em->flush();
```

but updating an item fails, silently, right after the getRepository():

```
$item = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Item')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
$item->setDescription(html_entity_decode($_POST['content']));
$this->doctrine->em->persist($item);
$this->doctrine->em->flush();
```

Same controller, and that is all the code in each action. All of my other controllers are fine, but this fails with nothing in any logs. Splitting the getRepository and find calls dies right after the getRepository. Moving the getRepository into the __construct causes update() to die with the find.

Thoughts? Leads? It seems anyone else on SO ends up either going a different direction or never having solved the problem.

Thanks!

---

Edit:
Add Models

Yaml

Item

```
Entities\Item:
    type: entity
    table: items
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
            notnull: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string(255)
            notnull: true
        slug:
            type: string(255)
            notnull: true
        description:
            type: string(255)
    manyToOne:
        type:
            targetEntity: Type
            inversedBy: item
            joinColumn:
                name: type_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    options:
        charset: utf8
        type: InnoDB
```

Type

```
Entities\Type:
    type: entity
    table: types
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
            notnull: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string(255)
            notnull: true
        slug:
            type: string(255)
            notnull: true
        description:
            type: string(255)
    oneToMany:
        items:
            targetEntity: Item
            orphanRemoval: true
            mappedBy: type
    manyToMany:
        fields:
            targetEntity: Field
            inversedBy: types
            joinTable:
                name: fields_types
                joinColumns:
                    type_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    field_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
    options:
        charset: utf8
        type: InnoDB
```

---

PHP

Item

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Entities\Item
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $fields;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fields = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add fields
     *
     * @param Entities\Field $fields
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addField(\Entities\Field $fields)
    {
        $this->fields[] = $fields;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove fields
     *
     * @param Entities\Field $fields
     */
    public function removeField(\Entities\Field $fields)
    {
        $this->fields->removeElement($fields);
    }

    /**
     * Get fields
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getFields()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }
    /**
     * @var Entities\Type
     */
    private $types;


    /**
     * Set types
     *
     * @param Entities\Type $types
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setTypes(\Entities\Type $types = null)
    {
        $this->types = $types;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get types
     *
     * @return Entities\Type 
     */
    public function getTypes()
    {
        return $this->types;
    }
    /**
     * @var Entities\Type
     */
    private $type;


    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param Entities\Type $type
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setType(\Entities\Type $type = null)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return Entities\Type 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
    /**
     * @var string $slug
     */
    private $slug;


    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

Type

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Entities\Type
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $items;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add items
     *
     * @param Entities\Item $items
     * @return Type
     */
    public function addItem(\Entities\Item $items)
    {
        $this->items[] = $items;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove items
     *
     * @param Entities\Item $items
     */
    public function removeItem(\Entities\Item $items)
    {
        $this->items->removeElement($items);
    }

    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $fields;


    /**
     * Add fields
     *
     * @param Entities\Field $fields
     * @return Type
     */
    public function addField(\Entities\Field $fields)
    {
        $this->fields[] = $fields;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove fields
     *
     * @param Entities\Field $fields
     */
    public function removeField(\Entities\Field $fields)
    {
        $this->fields->removeElement($fields);
    }

    /**
     * Get fields
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getFields()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }
    /**
     * @var string $slug
     */
    private $slug;


    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Type
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happends when you try with the method `$this->doctrine->em->find('Entities\Item', $id)` instead of `$this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Item')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id))` ?

Comment: I've been moving, and not able to test this like I'd like, but I'm 99% sure that I tried this and it made no difference.

Comment: Well... you are also trying to update with `persist()`. I suggest to use `merge()` like `$this->doctrine->em->merge($item);`

Comment: Will try that, but the issue also occurs in another controller where I'm not updating the item, I'm just reading it. Same first line, and dies at the same place.

Comment: Could you please post your modes\Item model?

Comment: Ok, Comcast figured out how to provide internet connections again so I'm back at it. Your first suggestion (just use a find instead of getRepository) gives me the same issue: Dies without error. I have noticed that my local version of PHP is 5.4, while the server is 5.3.3. This doesn't explain why the model loads correctly in some situations, and not in others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it. Unfortunately I do not know why. If anyone can explain to me why this fixes it (or what was broken to begin with) I'll accept your answer.

When loading the Item repository, it would fail silently. Loading the Type repository, and doing a findAll on it first fixed that. This may have all been because Items are a child of Type, but it seems odd to have to do a findAll() beforehand just to be able to load a specific Item.

For example, doing this in __construct():

```
$this->typeR = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Type');
$data['types'] = $this->typeR->findAll();
$this->itemR = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Item');
```

allows me to load items whenever necessary for that controller.

Again, this was just on the server. Locally it all worked fine.